# Troubles getting Simulink CIC decimator to work -- data type error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to get a simple Simulink model to work using an NCO and the CIC_decimator. I have looked at the Matlab example https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/gsm-digital-down-converter-1.html
and it works.

The error I get is "The number of input rows must be a multiple of the decimation factor".

I added the Convert blocks to try and make the data sizes work out, but that still hasn't worked. The NCO, by its self works, but the CIC has the wrong size inputs. I tried setting them to fixdt(1,20,18). I've spent many hours on this :(

The Matlab Example did not do anything special to make the data types work.

-- Thanks!

[image: Simulink 2020b model]